# Changing Command Super + Q

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.10, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I am really annoyed because I recently switched to GNOME and I lost a command, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, that I had with a special application.

Now, it shows the side menu (Ubuntu Dock) and numbers the applications.

I tried to change it at the keyboard options but the command is not even there!

I assume that it's a GNOME issue. But I am not very experienced and it is really annoying that I can't see the command in the Keyboard Command window.

This in on a XPS 13, Ubuntu 17.10, GNOME 3.26.1.

Answer (score 14):

You can disable this <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> behaviour by running the following command in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

Comment: is there something for ubuntu/kubuntu? [keyboard shortcut super+Q kills all active windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1637763/keyboard-shortcut-superq-kills-all-active-windows-and-then-enter-key-also-in-so)

Answer (score 5):

The Super Keys are overlayed by the gnome dock and don't show up in the normal settings.

I recommend dconf editor, for simplicity.

Go to org > gnome > shell > extensions > dash-to-dock.
Disable the *hot-keys*

It's a pain this is not controlled by the regular, central settings. At least on Bionic Beaver, where this is the default.